# SEM: Multivariate normality of the residuals?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, residuals, normality-assumption, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am currently reviewing the assumptions related to structural equation modeling and I read the following in an article on the subject: "Second, the assumption of normality applies to the residuals and is thus only relevant for dependent variables as defined in a given model; in contrast, the independent variables can take any distributional form at all (e.g., binary, count, bi-modal, long tail, etc.)."

**So I don't need to include my covariates and independent variables when testing for multivariate normality?**

Answer (score 2):

Most SEM experts probably agree that violations of multivariate normality are not as problematic nowadays given that appropriate correction methods for the standard errors and test statistics (which are most affected by non-normality) are now widely available in SEM software programs. I would therefore not worry too much about normality tests.

The most straightforward way to properly address non-normal data in CFA/SEM is to use robust ML estimation such as, for example, the Satorra-Bentler correction or other robust estimators (e.g., MLR or MLMV in Mplus). Some of these estimators can be used even with full information ML with missing data. Another approach is to use bootstrapping methods (Bollen-Stine bootstrap).

Correction methods such as robust ML estimators and bootstrapping provide the same parameter estimates as regular ML estimation but correct the fit statistics and parameter standard errors so that adequate statistical inference (tests of significance and confidence intervals) can be obtained.

In cases of severe non-normality, data transformations can be tried. Another option is to switch to a different estimation method that does not require multivariate normality such as weighted least squares (WLS) estimation. However, WLS requires very large samples (typically several thousand cases) to work properly. In most applications, using a robust version of the ML estimator is probably the most effective and efficient approach to handle non-normal data. See:

Finney, S. J., & DiStefano, C. (2006). Non-normal and categorical data in structural equation modeling. In G. R. Hancock & R. O. Mueller (Eds.), Structural equation modeling: A second course. Greenwich, CT: Information Age Publishing.

Comment: lavaan also has MLR and MLMV.

Comment: Thank you! I'm working with Onyx, I don't think it has MLR and MLMV, right?